# ERROR: Your wasm-opt version is 91, but we require a version >= 99

Tags: smart-contract, contracts, wasmi

I am doing the prepare your first contract tutorial on subtrate and i am getting the following error ERROR: Your wasm-opt version is 91, but we require a version >= 99.Can anyone please tell me how to solve it .

Comment: The following should help: https://docs.porta.network/developer-guide/smart-contracts/install-wasm-opt-version-101 and https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract/issues/272 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72905893/error-your-wasm-opt-version-is-91-but-we-require-a-version-99

Answer (score 1):

`wasm-opt` is part of the `binaryen` package. You can find out your local version by executing `wasm-opt --version`.

In [the `cargo-contract` installation instructions](https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract#installation) and the error message that you are getting there are notes on how to get a new version.

It comes down to installing `binaryen` in a version >= 99:

- [Debian/Ubuntu](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/binaryen): `apt-get install binaryen`
- [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/binaryen): `brew install binaryen`
- [Arch Linux](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/binaryen/): `pacman -S binaryen`
- Windows: [binary releases are available](https://github.com/WebAssembly/binaryen/releases)
- There is also `npm i wasm-opt -g`.

If none of this works you can download a binary release [here](https://github.com/WebAssembly/binaryen/releases) and put the `wasm-opt` binary into your environment.